# How can I get a value from other model, based in other value from that same other model?

Tags: python, django, django-models

How can I get the proper "sumvalue" in the example? (which I only know how to represent in SQL):

```
class Addition(models.Model):
    location = models.ForeignKey(Place, ...)
    a = models.DecimalField(...)
    b = models.DecimalField(...)

    @property
    def c(self):
        return self.a + self.b

class Result(models.Model):
    place = models.ForeignKey(Place, ...)
    # I only know how to represent in SQL
    sumvalue = SELECT c FROM Addition WHERE location = place
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, c is not a field, but a property.

You can call it on an instance:

```py
Addition.objects.all()[0].c()
```

Now for what you're trying to do, I really recommand you use annotate.

```py
from django.db.models import F

Addiction.objects.annotate(sum_a_b=F('a')+F('b'))
```

You then have an additional field in your query called `sum_a_b`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply @Guillaume, but adding the import and "Addiction.objects.annotate(sum_a_b=F('a')+F('b'))" in the class Result throws me the warning: "django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Models aren't loaded yet.". Do I need to use it in other place? Here's how it is now:
from django.db.models import F
...
class Addition(models.Model):
    ...

class Result(models.Model):
    place = models.ForeignKey(Place, ...)
    Addition.objects.annotate(sum_a_b=F('a')+F('b'))

Comment: My bad, I thought you were asking a query and not including it in another model. What you want is not good practise as you're repeating the information. To be honest, I don't really see the point of your Result model, since all info seems to be redundant.